# Music Player with ability to repeat a specific part of the song

Tags: ios, software-recommendation, music

I'm looking for an app with ability to repeat a part of the song playing. I need this as I'm using it for practicing listening skill.

Answer (score 3):

- Quick Time Player -

> Trim function

can do that.

Then use the Loop function to play over and over :)

- iTunes can do that (but not so handy)

Right click on the song- Get Info.

In there click on Options tab and select the Start and End time.

Answer (score 1):

Practice Player Pro - you can break down, loop and slow down sections of songs.

The Pro version is Free right now, but I suspect it will be paid at some point with a Free counterpart.

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/practice-player-pro/id1435249989?mt=8&ign-mpt=uo%3D4

Answer (score 0):

[JamUp](http://www.positivegrid.com/jamup/) can do that and lots more... Seems like a nice app!

To access this feature in JamUp:

- Launch the app
- Choose "Jam" from the tabs at the bottom of the app
- Click "Load Song" to load a song
- Click the play button to being playing the song
- When you reach the point where you want to START looping, Click the "A" button .
- When you reach the point where you want to STOP looping, Click the "B" button .
- Click the "Loop" icon under the A and B buttons to start looping
- When you dont want to loop anymore, click the "Loop" button again.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/154800)

Comment: Cool.... I've added some steps on how to access this feature in the app.

Answer (score -1):

[Learn That Song (PLAY Edition)](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/learn-that-song-play-edition-looping-for-music-app/id524438615?mt=8) app (not their Remix edition) is working with Apple Music streaming.